# Pictos font icon for searchfield repeating on Android 4.0.4 with Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: android, icons, sencha-touch-2, repeat, pictos

I upgraded my Android project to ST 2.2 and it is now using the new Pictos fonts for icons instead of images and webkit masks. I am having an issue where the icon for the searchfield repeats in the searchfield. How can I fix this? See below for the icon and the css.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this:

```
.x-field-search .x-field-input::before {
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```